# ASIHttpRequest - how to convert NSDictionary of params to url-encoded query param string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, ios-4.2

What is the preferred way to make a GET request with ASIHttpRequest using query params provided as an NSDictionary. 
How do I get 
from NSDictionary *params
to ?param1=value1&param2=value2    (percent-encoded)

Obviously I can construct the query part of the URL manually but it seems like there is probably a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass the query string as part of the URL. From the `ASIHTTPRequest` interface on [GitHub](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequest.h):

```
// The url for this operation, should include GET params in the query string where appropriate
NSURL *url;
```

If you don't want to roll your own dictionary-to-query-string method, take a look at the `GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments` category in Google Toolbox for Mac ([.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSDictionary%2BURLArguments.h), [.m](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSDictionary%2BURLArguments.m)). It adds a method, `gtm_httpArgumentString`, to `NSDictionary` that should be what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

I am not using ASIHTTPRequest, but I have a similar need for a URLRequest I make. Here is what I am doing:

```
- (NSString *) createParamString 
{
    NSDictionary *params = // build up the param dictionary    
    NSString *result = @"";
    id key;
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [params keyEnumerator];
    while (key = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@=%@&", key, [params objectForKey:key]];
    }
    result = [result substringToIndex:[result length] - 2];
    return [result stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
}
```

Not sure if it's perfect for all situations, but it's working well enough for me

Comment: If **params** is empty, you will have problems in the line:

    result = [result substringToIndex:[result length] - 2];

Try adding a condition:

if ([result length] >= 2)